# Override the spacing on the right of an in-line equation when followed by a punctuation mark

Tags: punctuation, inline

I set `\mathsurround` to `2pt` in order to have a bit more horizontal spacing between text and in-line equations. Is there a way to set it to `0pt` on the right whenever the in-line equation is followed by a punctuation mark?

For instance, the code

```
Let $x=0$ and $y=1$.
```

is typeset as in the first line below, while I would like it to be as in the second.

[image: Compiled code output]

Is there a way to achieve this without having to provide every time `\hspace{-2pt}`?

### Edit:

I have already considered @barbarabeeton's advice, that is, to include the punctuation before the final `$`, but some marks are typeset differently in text mode and math mode. Probably *punctuation marks* is a bit too restrictive, as I would like to include brackets () [] {} or even the apostrophe '. In addition I would like my code to be flexible, so whenever I decide to change something I don't have to edit the whole document.

Comment: although it really isn't a "best practice", you could include the punctuation before the final `$` sign.

Comment: Can you explain the reason why you want such a typographic style? I would say that the *default* version seems more reasonable in the first line.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the hint, I added some details to my question. Besides, I was looking for something closer to a "best practice"...

Comment: I try not to have inline equations followed by punctuation, it just looks bad, and in the worst case could change the meaning of $n$! Reword, make into a display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways. The first is to remove the math surround kern (with a macro before the punctuation); the second is to have punctuation inside the formula, but with a macro that takes care of the space factor and removes the kern.

In the example I show both methods. The third line is with zero `mathsurround, with the kerns added manually in order to show the output is the same.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\unms}{\kern-\mathsurround}

\newcommand{\fp}[1]{%
  \mbox{#1}%
  \xdef\fpuncsf{%
    \kern-\mathsurround
    \spacefactor\the\sfcode`#1\relax
  }%
  \aftergroup\fpuncsf
}

\setlength{\mathsurround}{2pt}

\begin{document}

Let $x=0$ and $y=1$\unms. There was a sentence ending period.

Let $x=0$ and $y=1\fp.$ There was a sentence ending period.

%% check
\mathsurround=0pt\def\?{\kern2pt }

Let \?$x=0$\? and \?$y=1$. There was a sentence ending period.

\end{document}
```

[image]